# Triple Hierarchy Fragment back navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments say GRANDPA, PA, ME.
There is one common container holding either one of these three fragments.

There is button in GRANDPA which calls PA.
Similarly there is button in PA which calls ME.
Inside ME there is a menu item "DONEtoPA" which returns back to PA.
Similarly there is a menu item in PA "DONEtoGRANDPA" which returns back to GRANDPA.

Everything is working fine(all navigations) except for a very small problem.

For the above scheme there can be three situations for user:

Situation 1: GRADPA calls PA and PA calls me...User presses DONEtoPA goes to PA then in PA presses DONEtoGRANDPA and goes to GRANDPA. - No issues navigation is fine.

Situation 2: GRADPA calls PA and PA calls me...User presses BACK goes to PA then in PA again presses BACK and goes to GRANDPA. - No issues navigation is fine.

Problem Situation 3 : GRADPA calls PA and PA calls me...User presses DONEtoPA goes to PA then in PA presses BACK. over here I have to press BACK button twice. On first BACK press nothing happens on second BACK press it goes to GRANDPA.

I am not able to understand why two times back press is required.

I have used addtobackstack(), hide() and show() commands of fragment to navigate and not replace().

CODE: GRANDPA

```
//BUTTON CALLING PA
    gp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(this);
            ft.addToBackStack(getTag());
            ft.add(R.id.LLfragmentconsole, new PA(), "PA");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

CODE PA:

```
//BUTTON CALLING PA
    pa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(this);
            ft.addToBackStack(getTag());
            ft.add(R.id.LLfragmentconsole, new ME(), "ME");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

//MENU ITEM DONEtoGRANDPA
    case R.id.mi_done:
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(this);
            ft.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("GRANDPA"));
            ft.commit();
   return true;
```

CODE ME:

```
 //MENU ITEM DONEtoPA
    case R.id.mi_done:
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(this);
            ft.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PA"));
            ft.commit();
   return true;
```

From what I understand, when I press DONEtoPA backstack record is still addition of fragment ME. Hence when I press BACK(first time) in PA fragment it tries to reverse this i.e remove Fragment ME.But since I have already done that in my DONEtoPA menu item this click is basically wasted. When I press BACK again backstack record changes to that of addition of PA fragment and hence on BACK press reverses it i.e removes fragment PA.

In nutshell, I want to remove this double back press action.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Stack and use it to store your fragments. Then you can create these methods in your activity to navigate into your fragment hierarchy :

SHOW A FRAGMENT :

```
private void showFragment(final Fragment fragment) 
{
    if (fragment == null)
        return;

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment);

    ft.commit();

    fragmentStack.push(fragment);
}
```

push a fragment :

```
public void pushFragment(final Fragment fragment) 
{
    closeKeaboard();

    if (fragment == null)
        return;

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_in_anim, R.anim.push_out_anim);

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment);

    ft.commit();

    fragmentStack.push(fragment);
}
```

Pop a fragment :

```
public void popFragment() 
{
    fragmentStack.pop();

    final Fragment fragment = fragmentStack.peek();

    if (fragment == null)
        return;

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pop_in_anim, R.anim.pop_out_anim);

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragment);

    ft.commit();
}
```

Then override OnBackPressed() :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    if(fragmentStack.size() == 1)
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    popFragment();
}
```

At last you can navigate like that :

```
pushFragment(this.paFragment);
popFragment();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i got it using popBackStack option.

Answer (score 0):

I got it using popBackStack(). It removed the backStack entry that was wasting my click.

Made following modifications in ME fragment

```
//MENU ITEM DONEtoPA
case R.id.mi_done:
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(this);
        ft.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PA"));
        ft.commit();
return true;
```